# Cups using print server and local printers simultaneously?

Tags: cups

At the place I work, we have a print server, where all the printers generally available are listed. In order to use that printer server (let's say it's name is printers.example.com) I had one line in my `client.conf` with `ServerName printers.example.com`. Now I want to use also some local network printers from my machine. However, I cannot change the configuration on the print server, since that is administered by our IT center and the local printers should not be visible globally anyway, and I can't find any way in CUPS to use local printers alongside the ones I get from the printer server (adding a second `ServerName` to the `client.conf` does not seem to be an option). Did I overlook something or is this, what I want, simply not possible with CUPS?